# Php if statement checking value of sometime undefined object

Tags: php, oop, if-statement, smarty

I am using smarty template system and am trying to do this for an if statement

```
{if isset($left_column_size) && !empty($left_column_size) && $category->name ne "Health"}
```

This works but if no category object is set for the given page I get php notices: 
Undefined index: category 
Trying to get property of non-object

What I really want is something as follows

```
{if isset($left_column_size) && !empty($left_column_size) {if isset($category)}&& $category->name ne "Health"{/if}}
```

If I try this I get the error Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template *code* too many shorthand attributes.  Does anyone know what the right thing to do here to get rid of those php error notices is? Thanks

Comment: If you're using `empty()` you don't need `isset()` - `empty()` on an undefined var will return `false` and not throw a warning/notice.

Comment: I tried using `&& empty($category->name eq "Health")` and still get all the same php notices

Comment: but empty() also returns true on "false-y" values, so `left-size = 0` will return a false positive.

Comment: Sounds like something specific to smarty (I.e. that they prefer you to have simple if statements to encourage simple view code). The empty vs isset issue is still a good step to takw. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were on the right track. Try something along these lines

```
if(!empty($left_column_size) &&
  ((!empty($category) && $category->name ne "Health") 
    || empty($category))
```

Comment: The thing about this is I also need it to work when $category is empty.

Comment: @Trey Edited. Something more like that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by doing:

```
{if isset($left_column_size) && !empty($left_column_size) && 
( empty($category) || (!empty($category) &&$category->name ne "Health Topics"))}
```